# SQL conversion error because of datetime2

Tags: sql-server

I have a view in a SQL Server 2008 database that has a datetime2 field.  I need to be able to query from that view via a linked SQL server 2005.  When I run open my cursor and fetch the records I get a "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string." error.  How do I make the cursor convert the datetime2 appropriately?

Here is my query that is failing

```
DECLARE @time DateTime

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [DateTime] FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASENAME].[dbo].[ViewName] 
  WHERE Name = 'blah'

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @time

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  Print @time
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @time
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you try `SELECT CAST([DateTime] AS DateTime) AS [DateTime] FROM ...`

Comment: `DATETIME2` has a larger range of acceptable values - you could end up with a date e.g. `0001/01/01` which is entirely valid in `DATETIME2` but will cause this error in `DATETIME`

Comment: @marc_s - You should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to declare cursor in following way:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT cast([DateTime] as DateTime) FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASENAME].[dbo].[ViewName] 
  WHERE Name = 'blah'
```

**BUT**

if remote values from DATETIME2 field is outside the allowed to DateTime type, then try the following

```
DECLARE @time NVARCHAR(100)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT CAST([DateTime] as NVArCHAR(100)) FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[DATABASENAME].[dbo].[ViewName] 
  WHERE Name = 'blah'

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @time

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  Print @time
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @time
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```